# Overriding a method signature using virtual

Tags: c#

As everybody knows using virtual keyword for a method in a class allows us to override it in its derived sub-class. However, method still has to stick to the same signature e.g. return value, argument and etc.

Question: in C#, how can I can override the signature as well? is this possible?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is not possible.  You can create an overload, though, if you need it.

**Edit**

To make my case against `new`, please consider the case where you have a base object, and one that inherits from it.  By placing `new` before the method of which you're attempting to "change" the method signature, you're actually wasting four key strokes.

```
public class Base {
    public string Foo () { return null; }
}

public class Inherited : Base {
    public new int Foo () { return 0; }
}
```

Now, `Inherited` has two methods:

```
public string Foo () { return null; }
public int Foo () { return 0; }
```

You are not actually *changing* the method signature.  Thus, the `new` keyword isn't even needed.  You will get the same effect without it:

```
public class Inherited : Base {
    public int Foo () { return 0; }
}
```

The use of `new` is to [override a non-virtual member of a base class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/435f1dw2.aspx):

```
public class Base { 
    public string Foo () { return null; }
}

public class Inherited : Base {
    public new string Foo () { return "Something else..."; }
}
```

But you will run into issues with this if you don't pay attention to this subtlety.  With `virtual` you get a virtual look-up table that will map your functions to the correct call.  With `new`, you will not.  If you pass in `Inherited` where a `Base` object is required (this will work, of course), the `Base` class's `Foo()` will be called!  Not, the `Inherited` "override" of `Foo()`.

**This is not the same behavior as overriding a virtual member.**

```
public static class MyClass {
    public string MyMethod (Base @base) {
        return @base.Foo ();
    }
}

[Test]
public void then_it_should_return_non_null () {
    var obj = new Inherited ();
    var result = MyClass.MyMethod(obj);  // obj will get upcasted to Base
    Assert.That (result, Is.EqualTo(obj.Foo ())); // Assert fails!
}

[Test]
public void inherited_should_return_correct_value ()
{
    var obj = new Inherited ();
    var result = obj.Foo ();  // will access the "new" method, hiding Base's implementation
    Assert.That (result, Is.Not.Null);  // Assert passes! 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can hide the old implementation with the `new` keyword. However, the base class won't be able to see it.

```
class Base {
   public string Foo() { }
}

class Sub : Base {
   new public int Foo() { }
}
```

`new` is only needed if the calling signature is the same.

Comment: That doesn't change the signature, though.

Comment: @JamesD'Angelo yes it can change the signature.

Comment: It does not change the signature.  It overrides a non-virtual class member.

Comment: A quick sanity check in VS gives me a warning: "The member 'foo.bar()' does not hide an inherited member. The new keyword is not required."

Comment: @JamesD'Angelo are they public?

Comment: Yes, they are public. (Your fixed answer now no longer applies to the user's question, imho.)

Answer (score 0):

At that point you are just making a new method. But, if you want to simply create a new method with a new method signature, and then call the base.OtherMethod(param1, param2)... you can.

The point I'm trying to make is that, if you intend to create a method with the same name as in the base class, but with a different signature **but you still want to just call the base class**, then you can.

For example:

```
// In base class - note, the "virtual" isn't necessary.
public virtual void PostMessage(string message, DateTime entryDate) { ... }
```

Then you think... "Oh man, I wish this base class had an overload for that method that didn't require the date... what can I do?!"

```
// In your sub-class.
public void PostMessage(string message)
{
    base.PostMessage(message, DateTime.Now);
}
```

Comment: thanks for your comment. I see what you saying but didn't get the last statement "and then call the base.OtherMethod(param1, param2)... you can."   can you give me some ideas on that?

Answer (score 0):

You are talking about creating a new method. If the name is the same, but the parameters are different (return type and parameter's type and number of parameters) you actually are overloading.