# Casting classes in C#

Tags: c#, casting

I have a question, why in this code, One() method is execute from class B and Two() method  is executed from class A? I know that is doing casting, but I don't understand the way is working. By the way, any good link or book with this kind of tricks will be much appreciated.
Than you.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        B b = new B();
        A a = (A)b;

        a.One(); 
        a.Two(); 
    }
}

public class A
{
    public virtual void One()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("A One");
    }
    public void Two()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("A Two");
    }
}

public class B : A
{
    public override void One()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("B One");
    }
    public new void Two()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("B Two");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is because `Two()` is not a virtual method. The only time `Two()` will be called from class `B` is if you are specifically looking at an instance of `B`. Class `A` doesn't have a lookup table for a virtual method when calling `Two()` so nobody knows to look elsewhere for a different method.

You can see more details in my answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12965958/overriding-a-method-signature-using-virtual/12965973#12965973).

Comment: Very nice clarification with respect of the "virtual" method and lookup class structure to get resolution

Comment: @DRapp - thanks! This is definitely oversimplified, but it's a good start for somebody who wants to lookup VTABLES and memory structures.  =)

Comment: Thank you, that's answered my question!

Comment: No worries, glad to help. It's an interesting topic to dig into.

Answer (score 0):

The Two() method is not virtual in class A (so it does not allow it to be overridden, almost for the same reason you had to make B.Two() as new - otherwise the compiler would have complained).

So when you dont have a virtual method in the base class it is not meant to be overridden. Thus when you cast object of type B to type A the call to Two() method is bound to the method table of type A and not type B.

You can read more about it here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6fawty39(v=vs.80).aspx
http://www.akadia.com/services/dotnet_polymorphism.html